# Cocoa: how safe is it to make an app that is coupled with python subroutines?

Tags: python, cocoa

I want to make a Cocoa OS X app. I would prefer to use python scripts in it's core. However, not sure how safe is it. I know that python penetration is quite high, but what about version conflicts and migrations? Is it worth bundling whole python runtime into the OS X app?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider "unsafe"? How would you invoke the Python code?

Comment: @zneak unsafe - non-working app. Python code is invoked with `NSTask`.

Comment: Why would you want to use python scripts in its core? Mostly, anything Python can do, you can also do with Objective-C and Cocoa.

Comment: @dreamlax beacse I want to make a cross-platform app, and keep as much as possible platform-independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.... what this really boils down to is compatibility issues across versions, something that scripting languages are notoriously bad at maintaining.   Python does better than most, but it is still quite problematic.

Apple has *generally* shipped legacy versions of interpreters on the system for exactly this reason.   Thus, if you do rely on the system installed Python, I would recommend locking to a particular version.   I.e. use `/usr/bin/python2.6` and not the generic `/usr/bin/python`.

The alternative is as you state;  bundle the python interpreter and any needed resources into your app.   That is a bit of a pain the butt to do, but it addresses the compatibility issue.  More or less;  the reality is that Python is, effectively, an interface to the OS and, thus, is quite large with potential to break across any release.   Not much you can about that, though.

Another possibility is to go the route that @kindall proposes;   use PyObjC and implement your Cocoa application entirely or mostly in Python.   Works fine.  Been there, done that, and wouldn't do it again, frankly, as the maintenance/debugging issues of large scale scripted applications are nasty.

As an alternative, you might want to investigate using Lua (http://www.lua.org) as it is very much designed to be embedded in applications.   Lua has a tiny interpreter and you can fully control exactly what features of your app are accessible at runtime.   For example, World of Warcraft's UI is mostly implemented as Lua gluing together a set of fast UI primitives.  Fully customizable on the client side, which is really impressive when you consider the security implications.

Comment: Wow, lots of options. Thanks. Do I understand correctly, that after you did everything above you prefer to go the LUA way? I'm a bit familiar with it, so i could do it. My idea, is to make a cross-platform console app, that can be used outside the UI and the bundle it to platform specific "containers" (Foundation, Forms etc). Pretty much the same way as Sublime Text made.

Comment: I was the lead or co-lead engineer on PyObjC since Guido kicked it out of Python in 1994 up through ~2003ish (Ronald Oussoren, though, contributed far more of far greater value than I ever did and has now taken over the project entirely) and, yeah, if I were going the route you describe, I would go with Lua....

Comment: Since you mentioned Sublime Text, note that they ship a zipped distribution of Python bundled inside the app (Python 3.3 in the Sublime Text 3 betas). See Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/python3.3.zip.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [py2app](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/py2app). It will bundle a Python executable, all the libraries you need, and your script together into a single executable. You can then add other executables (e.g. your Objective-C parts) into that app bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will take a look if it serves the purpose. I would also bundle the python itself, to be honest, but I'm quite concerned about weight overhead. I will give it a go. Thanks again.

Comment: Solves a slightly different problem than what OP has, but is definitely worth investigating!

Comment: Trust me, you will be happiest if you put Python in your app bundle. The company I work for has a multi-platform app with a Python API and we used to use the system's installed Python, but it was a support nightmare. Instead we now bundle a version of Python we know that works, and support is much easier. By the way, I am not suggesting you write your entire app in Python, you can make an app bundle with py2app and then combine it with, or include it in, another bundle.